# Accessing GPS Data without using Core Location Framework

Tags: ios, gps, location-services

Can I obtain the device location data from GPS chip without using the Core Location Framework provided by the Apple iOS SDK? I am aware of the fact that I can't specifically access the GPS chip using Core Location Framework but I want to do it without using Core Location Framework.

Answer (score 0):

No, programmatically you cannot access the GPS chip without using the Core Location Framework.

Comment: can you cite any credible article for that?

Comment: If you participate in the Apple Developper Program, and if you have some experience debvelopping for ios, you may have noticed, that you don't have any acces to the hardware, outside the Apple Api. It may work in jailbreaked devices, but not in an regular ios.